# JSF navigation problem

Tags: jsf

I am not able to navigate from one page to another after clicking the button on the page. I have defined the navigation rules.

```
<managed-bean>
 <description>helloWorld</description>
 <managed-bean-name>helloWorld</managed-bean-name>
 <managed-bean-class>com.ritz.web.HelloWorld</managed-bean-class>
 <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<navigation-rule>
 <from-view-id>/HelloWorldProg.xhtml</from-view-id>
 <navigation-case>
  <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
  <to-view-id>/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
 </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<application>
 <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

web.xml is

```
<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>faces/HelloWorld.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You can set nav. rulez in faces-config.xml if you are using JSF 1.x. If you are using JSF 2, just put the path in the "action" value, example: `<h:commandButton value="Click me!" action="path/page.xhtml/>`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you you need a method to set action after button click:

```
public String nextPage()
{
    if (username.equals("guest") && password.equals("guest"))
    {
        return "loginSuccess";
    }
    return "loginFailure";
}
```

Next thing you need to do is connect your button action attribute with method:

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit Values" action="#{YourBean.nextPage}"/>
```

Then you need to do is set a navigation rules:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <description></description>
    <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>loginSuccess</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/loginSuccess.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
<navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>loginFailure</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/loginFailure.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>        
</navigation-rule>    
</faces-config>
```

And one last thing. If you have mapping like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You should put everywehere faces/login.xhtml, faces/success.xhtml and so on.